# Can't Create MYSQL DataBase Tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create MYSQL tables for my DataBase but I keep getting an error

Here is my code

```
CREATE DATABASE Hospitals;

CREATE TABLE hospital (
    hospitalId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    postcode VARCHAR(10),
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(20),
    emailAddress VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (hospitalId),
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE wards (
    wardID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    specialisation VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (wardID),
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE staff (
    staffId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    foreName VARCHAR(50),
    surName VARCHAR(50),
    position VARCHAR(50),
    salary DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (staffId)) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE patients (
    niNumber VARCHAR(50),
    name VARCHAR(100),
    dob DATE,
    sex VARCHAR(10),
    nokName VARCHAR(100),
    nokPhone VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY niNumber) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE medications (
    medicationId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    contraIndications VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (medicationId)) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO hospital (hospitalId, name, postcode, phoneNumber, emailAddress)
        VALUES(1, 'Bangor', 'LL72GW', '01276541789', 'Bangor.Hospital@gmail.com'),
            VALUES(2, 'london', 'SW1A 0AA', '01673531789', 'London.Hospital@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO wards (wardId, name, specialisation)
        VALUES(1, 'Ward1', 'Brain Surgery'),
            VALUES(2, 'Ward2', 'Heart Surgery');
INSERT INTO staff (staffId, foreName, surName, position, salary)
        VALUES(1, 'Malcolm', 'Gross', 'Manager', '50000.0'),
            VALUES(1, 'Lewis', 'Castle', 'Surgeon', '30000.0');
INSERT INTO patients (niNumber, name, dob, sex, nokName, nokPhone)
        VALUES('001AFCY6', 'Sam', '20-02-2002', 'male', 'David', '09876543268'),
            VALUES('0SSHD2J3', 'Jim', '19-09-1977', 'male', 'Terry', '06789347382');
INSERT INTO medications (medicationId, name, contraIndications)
        VALUES(1, 'Heart Medicine', 'Dont Use if heart is ok'),
            VALUES(2, 'Antibiotics', 'Dont use if patient is feeling well');
```

But the error I keep getting is `Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES(2, 'Antibiotics', 'Dont use if patient is feeling well')' at line 3`

I have no idea why I am getting such an error

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix my error please

Many Thanks

Comment: You only need 1 VALUES clause per insert statement. Voting to close as typo and see manual with sentence starting INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: Also there is a `,` too much in the create statements for the tables `hospital` and `wards` and `patients`, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fba8816e8ab3860d4fc85591cfa8bc3a)  P.S. You should make it a habit to start with the FIRST error given, not with the LAST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use 2 VALUES keywords in your INSERT statements. So you  updated INSERT statement should look alike -

```
INSERT INTO hospital (hospitalId, name, postcode, phoneNumber, emailAddress)
        VALUES(1, 'Bangor', 'LL72GW', '01276541789', 'Bangor.Hospital@gmail.com'),
              (2, 'london', 'SW1A 0AA', '01673531789', 'London.Hospital@gmail.com');
```

And you have to get rid of last commas in first 2 tables also -

```
CREATE TABLE hospital (
    hospitalId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    postcode VARCHAR(10),
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(20),
    emailAddress VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (hospitalId) --,     This should be removed.
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE wards (
    wardID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    specialisation VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (wardID) --,     This should be removed.
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```